# Instance created in multipass without IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ip, multipass

The error is the following, when creating an instance in multipass it is created without an IP address.

1. I run the multipass launch command, and the instance is created normally.

```
C:\Windows\system32>multipass launch
Launched: treasured-tamandua
```

2. Then, I run the multipass ls command and that's where I see the problem, the instance is created but without an IP address.

```
C:\Windows\system32>multipass ls
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
accepting-oriole        Deleted           --               Not Available
achieving-lagomorph     Deleted           --               Not Available
attentive-killifish     Deleted           --               Not Available
clean-reptile           Deleted           --               Not Available
closing-oilbird         Deleted           --               Not Available
main-zorilla            Deleted           --               Not Available
new-vm2                 Deleted           --               Not Available
treasured-tamandua      Running           N/A              Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

Therefore I would like to know how to create this instance that has an IP address assigned to it.